I need help with anza wallet-adapter
I'm setting up a fresh project and having trouble with setting up the wallet connect.
Here are the given errors;
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ledgerhq/hw-transport/lib-es/Transport.js 225:26-48
export 'TransportRaceCondition' (imported as 'TransportRaceCondition') was not found in '@ledgerhq/errors' (possible exports: AccountNameRequiredError, AccountNotSupported, AmountRequired, BluetoothRequired, BtcUnmatchedApp, CantOpenDevice, CantScanQRCode, CashAddrNotSupported, ClaimRewardsFeesWarning, CurrencyNotSupported, DBNotReset, DBWrongPassword, DeviceAppVerifyNotSupported, DeviceExtractOnboardingStateError, DeviceGenuineSocketEarlyClose, DeviceHalted, DeviceInOSUExpected, DeviceNameInvalid, DeviceNeedsRestart, DeviceNotGenuineError, DeviceOnDashboardExpected, DeviceOnDashboardUnexpected, DeviceOnboardingStatePollingError, DeviceShouldStayInApp, DeviceSocketFail, DeviceSocketNoBulkStatus, DisabledTransactionBroadcastError, DisconnectedDevice, DisconnectedDeviceDuringOperation, DustLimit, ETHAddressNonEIP, EnpointConfigError, EthAppPleaseEnableContractData, ExpertModeRequired, FeeEstimationFailed, FeeNotLoaded, FeeNotLoadedSwap, FeeRequired, FeeTooHigh, FirmwareNotRecognized, FirmwareOrAppUpdateRequired, GasLessThanEstimate, GenuineCheckFailed, HardResetFail, HwTransportError, HwTransportErrorType, InvalidAddress, InvalidAddressBecauseDestinationIsAlsoSource, InvalidNonce, InvalidXRPTag, LanguageNotFound, LatestMCUInstalledError, LedgerAPI4xx, LedgerAPI5xx, LedgerAPIError, LedgerAPIErrorWithMessage, LedgerAPINotAvailable, LockedDeviceError, MCUNotGenuineToDashboard, ManagerAppAlreadyInstalledError, ManagerAppDepInstallRequired, ManagerAppDepUninstallRequired, ManagerAppRelyOnBTCError, ManagerDeviceLockedError, ManagerFirmwareNotEnoughSpaceError, ManagerNotEnoughSpaceError, ManagerUninstallBTCDep, MaxFeeTooLow, NetworkDown, NetworkError, NoAccessToCamera, NoAddressesFound, NoDBPathGiven, NotEnoughBalance, NotEnoughBalanceBecauseDestinationNotCreated, NotEnoughBalanceInParentAccount, NotEnoughBalanceToDelegate, NotEnoughGas, NotEnoughGasSwap, NotEnoughSpendableBalance, NotSupportedLegacyAddress, OpReturnDataSizeLimit, PairingFailed, PasswordIncorrectError, PasswordsDontMatchError, PeerRemovedPairing, PendingOperation, PriorityFeeHigherThanMaxFee, PriorityFeeTooHigh, PriorityFeeTooLow, RecipientRequired, RecommendSubAccountsToEmpty, RecommendUndelegation, ReplacementTransactionUnderpriced, SequenceNumberError, StatusCodes, SyncError, TimeoutTagged, TransactionHasBeenValidatedError, TransportError, TransportExchangeTimeoutError, TransportInterfaceNotAvailable, TransportOpenUserCancelled, TransportPendingOperation, TransportStatusError, TransportWebUSBGestureRequired, UnavailableTezosOriginatedAccountReceive, UnavailableTezosOriginatedAccountSend, UnexpectedBootloader, UnknownMCU, UnresponsiveDeviceError, UpdateFetchFileFail, UpdateIncorrectHash, UpdateIncorrectSig, UpdateYourApp, UserRefusedAddress, UserRefusedAllowManager, UserRefusedDeviceNameChange, UserRefusedFirmwareUpdate, UserRefusedOnDevice, WebsocketConnectionError, WebsocketConnectionFailed, WrongAppForCurrency, WrongDeviceForAccount, WrongDeviceForAccountPayout, WrongDeviceForAccountRefund, addCustomErrorDeserializer, createCustomErrorClass, deserializeError, getAltStatusMessage, serializeError)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@toruslabs/eccrypto/dist/browser.js 7:19-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/jukezispilled/flip3/node_modules/@toruslabs/eccrypto/dist'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 2:16-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/jukezispilled/flip3/node_modules/cipher-base'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/hash-base/index.js 4:16-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/jukezispilled/flip3/node_modules/hash-base'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/micro-ftch/index.js 57:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/jukezispilled/flip3/node_modules/micro-ftch'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/micro-ftch/index.js 58:16-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/jukezispilled/flip3/node_modules/micro-ftch'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/micro-ftch/index.js 59:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/Users/jukezispilled/flip3/node_modules/micro-ftch'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/micro-ftch/index.js 65:6-20
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/Users/jukezispilled/flip3/node_modules/micro-ftch'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

This is being tracked here https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/issues/950
